# Switching to mobile view from flag history page

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web

I was clicking the mobile link (bottom of the page) from the flag history a couple of times and was seeing no changes (except page refreshs)

I then remembered the flag history page was not accessible on mobile view.

I think this response (or lack of it) is not very user-friendly. I suggest that:
*whenever you try to switch to mobile view on a page that doesn't support such feature, to get redirected to the home page in mobile view*

Comment: You dont think users will fight with the fact that links keep sending them to the homepage and post about that?

Comment: @kor that wont be the case, they will switch from fullsite to mobile, then they should not be able to get to a non-mobile page from there. The loop gets interrupted

Answer (score 1):

How about there is a page that informs them the page they were attempting to access is not available on mobile?

This way you don't have to worry about users figuring it out because it will not refresh or because it keep redirecting them to the homepage. You know why the page is not working and dont have to worry your phone is being funny or the site is.

Comment: i don't think an error is a good option. What is wrong with redirecting to homepage? once they get there, they won't be able to land on any non-mobile page again

Comment: @ajax333221 Not error, A page telling them the page they were on was not mobile available and a link to the homepage? The same issue results with the homepage as does with not refreshing the page, users sit there trying to figure out why their link keeps screwing up and going to the homepage.